# Regex for a string with multpile test cases

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

I am trying to figure out a specific regex for a string that may result out in a different format:

Example:

```
"Fluid 13.4"

"Fluid 13.4 gm% fluid_haemo 12.0-14.0"

"Fluid gm% 13.4 fluid_haemo 12.0-14.0"

"Fluid gm% fluid_hameo 12.0-14.0 13.4"

"fluid fluid fluid 13.4"

"fluid rex cell (FRC) 13.4"

"Fluid rex cell 1800"
```

**My actual requirements is kinda tricky:**

1. I want the "fluid" or whatever that comes as a first word in the string.
2. The number "13.4" or in some cases, it might not be a decimal.
3. If in the string there's continuous words followed by a decimal or a number.

   String 1 : "Fluid, 13.4"Edit

   String 2 : "Fluid 13.4"

   String 3: "Fluid 13.4"

   String 4: Fluid 13.4"

   String 5: "Fluid Fluid Fluid 13.4"

   String 6: "Fluid rex cell (FRC) 13.4"

   String 7: "Fluid rex cell 1800"

What I have tried :

```
[a-zA-Z].* \d.*\.+\d.*

[a-zA-Z].* [\d.]+ (?=[a-z%\/])
```

But for obvious reasons, my regex is very case specific and I for sure don't know in what format the string would be resulted.

Is there any way or a regex that could work out for such an issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might use

```
\b([a-zA-Z]+)(?: [a-zA-Z]+%.*?)? (\d+(?:\.\d+)?)(?!\S)
```

- `\b` A word boundary to prevent a partial match
- `([a-zA-Z]+)` Capture **group 1**, match 1+ char a-zA-Z
- `(?: [a-zA-Z]+%.*?)?`  Optionally match a space and chars a-z followed by `%` and a space
- `(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)` Capture **group 2**, match 1+ digits with an optional decimal part
- `(?!\S)` Assert a whitespace boundary to the right

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/wvNpod/1)

```
import re

strings = [
    "Fluid 13.4",
    "Fluid 13.4 gm% fluid_haemo 12.0-14.0",
    "Fluid gm% 13.4 fluid_haemo 12.0-14.0",
    "Fluid gm% fluid_hameo 12.0-14.0 13.4"
]
pattern=r"\b([a-zA-Z]+)(?: [a-zA-Z]+%.*?)? (\d+(?:\.\d+)?)(?!\S)"
for s in strings:
    print(re.findall(pattern, s))
```

Output

```
[('Fluid', '13.4')]
[('Fluid', '13.4')]
[('Fluid', '13.4')]
[('Fluid', '13.4')]
```

**Edit**

To capture the "words" included in the first group, you could include optionally repeat matching spaces followed by 1+ times any of the allowed characters which end with a whitspace boundary at the right.

```
\b([A-Za-z]+\b(?:\s+[\w()]+)*(?!\S)).*?\s(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)(?!\S)
```

- `\b` A word boundary to prevent a partial match
- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `[A-Za-z]+\b` Match 1+ chars A-Za-z and a word boundary
  - `(?:\s+[\w()]+)*` Optionally repeat whitespace chars followed by 1+ times any of the allowed chars in the character class
  - `(?!\S)` Assert a whitespace boundary to the right
- `)` Close group 1
- `.*?\s` Match as least as possible chars and then a whitespace char
- `(` Capture **group 2**

  - `\d+(?:\.\d+)?`
- `)` Close group 2
- `(?!\S)` Assert a whitespace boundary to the right

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/iyLLu6/1)

Comment: I suspect it should be `\b([A-Za-z]+)\b.*?\s(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)(?!\S)`. Just came up with this since I thought all strings should match.

Comment: For the test cases number 3 and 4, it's not really working out.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Ah I see, I missed that part. I updated it with an optional part.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew You can post that one of course :-)

Comment: Hi, for the test cases 3 and 4, instead of matching the two parts that I need, it's actually considering the whole series of characters up until '13.4'

Comment: @JimitVaghela I have updated the pattern with an optional part that directly matches a string containing `%`

Comment: @JimitVaghela The values are in capture group 1 and group 2.

Comment: @JimitVaghela Yes, I have added example code to get the group values. You can also look at Wiktor's answer if the `%` part is not mandatory.

Comment: @JimitVaghela Perhaps like `^([A-Za-z]+\b(?:\s+[\w()]+)*(?!\S)).*?\s+(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)(?!\S)` https://regex101.com/r/9MgRSd/1

Comment: @thefourthbird Yes, exactly.

Comment: @JimitVaghela I have added it to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```py
import re
rx = r'\b([A-Za-z]+)\b.*?\s(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)(?!\S)'
texts = ["Fluid 13.4","Fluid 13.4 gm% fluid_haemo 12.0-14.0","Fluid gm% 13.4 fluid_haemo 12.0-14.0","Fluid gm% fluid_hameo 12.0-14.0 13.4"]
for text in texts:
    match = re.search(rx, text)
    if match:
        print(text, '=>', f'{match.group(1)} {match.group(2)}')

# => Fluid 13.4 => Fluid 13.4
#    Fluid 13.4 gm% fluid_haemo 12.0-14.0 => Fluid 13.4
#    Fluid gm% 13.4 fluid_haemo 12.0-14.0 => Fluid 13.4
#    Fluid gm% fluid_hameo 12.0-14.0 13.4 => Fluid 13.4
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/LCHsV3) and the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Yb3qxG/1).

*Details*:

- `\b` - a word boundary
- `([A-Za-z]+)` - Group 1: an ASCII letter word
- `\b` - a word boundary
- `.*?` - any zero or more chars other than line break chars, as few as possible
- `\s` - a whitespace
- `(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)` - Group 2: one or more digits and then an optional sequence of a `.` and one or more digits
- `(?!\S)` - right-hand side whitespace boundary.

Comment: Nice one for sure ++

Comment: Hi, I have added two new test strings. Any suggestions for that would be highly appreciated.

Comment: @JimitVaghela My solution [works](https://regex101.com/r/Yb3qxG/2).

Comment: It certainly does capture the "fluid" and "13.4" but let's say in the last two string that I recently added, in that portion, I also want to match the words that are all present as well as the number?

Comment: @JimitVaghela So, you want `\b([A-Za-z]+\b.*?)\s+(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)(?!\S)`? See [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/Yb3qxG/3)

Comment: In only the last two cases only, yes. But since the output may vary, would you suggest using two different regex that you have suggested?

Comment: @JimitVaghela Without exact requirements, it is just a guess game. Try `(?i)\b([a-z]+(?:\s+(?:\([a-z]+\)|[a-z]+))+)\s+(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)(?!\S)`, see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/Yb3qxG/4). This will also capture any one or more whitespace separated words or (words) after the initial word.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your input always has `Fluid` and then the first numbers after that are the ones you want.  If that's the case you can use

```
Fluid\b.*?(\d*\.?\d*)
```

This matches the text `Fluid` followed by a 'boundary' character, then skips the smallest number of characters it can until it finds as many decimal numeric characters as it can, an optional decimal point followed by as many decimal characters as it can.

This is of course specific to your case and relies on `Fluid` always being present.

In your last case it would match 12.0 not 13.4